Is adam (as) created by Allah’: swt hands or by “be” and he was?
Assalamu alaikum my brothers and sisters. I was just hoping you guys could help me with something im confused about.
There are some ahadith which mention 4 things were created by Allah by his hands which also include Adam and for the rest He only said "Be". Are these authentic? If so then how can we reconcile it with quran 3:59 which specifically mentions that Adam was too created through "Be"? And also, Allah says in the Quran that he created Adam with his hands, but in verse 3:59 he says the similarity between Adam and Esa is that they wore both created by “be”.
I was hoping someone could educate me on this. Thanks!
